# Why is "ultimate addons for wpbakery page builder" plugin bombing when I activate it?

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

I'm getting the following error in my server logs:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'AIO_Icon_Manager' not found in
>   [...]/wp-content/plugins/Ultimate_VC_Addons/Ultimate_VC_Addons.php:359

Answer (score 0):

The module files in the version of Ultimate Addons that I have are capitalized:

[image: screenshot of modules directory in Finder]

But the code that actually looks for the files doesn't capitalize the filenames. Some servers are set up to be case-sensitive and some aren't. Because mine is, I was forced to rename the files, downcasing them to match what the code was expecting, and then the plugins started working again.